# C# Datatable Escape Special Characters

Tags: c#, string, google-maps, special-characters

I have a a datatable which I need to loop through and remove any special characters such as ' and & and also any empty strings.

The columns I need to check are:

```
Address1 - need to be checked for special chars and empty strings
Address2 - need to be checked for special chars and empty strings
Address3 - need to be checked for special chars and empty strings
lat - need to check its not 0
lng - need to check its not 0
```

I then need to fix that record in the datatable and move on to the next one and repeat until the whole datatable has been fixed. I do not want to update the underlying database.

I have a google maps api webpage and it fails if any of the fields are empty or contain special chars. I will bind the fixed datatable to the maps.

Any help will be much appreciated,

thank you

Comment: If you show some of your actual code we could help to fix the issues. Or is this a 'write-the-code-please' kind of question?

Comment: Your workaround is nill,Simply you are posting your requirement to do your homework.Add some code whatever you written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `foreach`-loop and modify the `DataRows`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    string addr1 = row.Field<string>("Address1");
    addr1 = addr1.Replace("'", "").Replace("&", "").Replace(" ", "");
    row.SetField("Address1", addr1);

    string addr2 = row.Field<string>("Address2");
    addr2 = addr2.Replace("'", "").Replace("&", "").Replace(" ", "");
    row.SetField("Address2", addr2);

    string addr3 = row.Field<string>("Address3");
    addr3 = addr3.Replace("'", "").Replace("&", "").Replace(" ", "");
    row.SetField("Address3", addr3);

    string lat = row.Field<string>("lat");
    lat = lat.Replace("0", "");
    row.SetField("lat", lat);

    string lng = row.Field<string>("lng");
    lng = lng.Replace("0", "");
    row.SetField("lng", lng);
}
```

If `lat` and `lng` are actually `int`-columns, `SetField` supports nullable types:

```
// ...
int lat = row.Field<int>("lat");
int? newLat = null;
if(lat != 0) newLat = lat;
row.SetField("lat", newLat);

int lng = row.Field<int>("lng");
int? newLng = null;
if (lng != 0) newLng = lat;
row.SetField("lng", newLng);
// ...
```

Comment: thank you, just needed pointing in the right direction. appreciate your help